# Is it possible to “hide” users via YouTube’s API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a handful of YouTube channels and I would like to be able to easily propagate the [“hiding”](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9482361) of trolls etc. when I come across them and I was thinking of making a script that I could feed a list or individual accounts to have it go through and “hide” the accounts preemptively from all channels.

I looked at the [Comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) and [Channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) sections of the [YouTube Data API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs) but none of the methods/endpoints seem to provide this.

Am I missing something? Is it documented elsewhere? If not, are there any tools that provide access to the unofficial/undocumented API endpoint that YouTube itself is using when “hiding” users?